# Mongodb sum up values day by day

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm trying to sum up values day by day, for example if day 1's net income = 600, day 2 net income will be = day2's net income + day1's net income. How can I properly sum up the values by day increments? Here's what I've tried by it doesn't include the previous day's net income.

```
    db.collection.aggregate([
      {
        $match: {
          date: {
            $gte: new Date("2023-05-31")
          }
        }
      },
      {
        $sort: {
          date: 1
        }
      },
      {
        $group: {
          _id: null,
          data: {
            $push: {
              date: "$date",
              income: "$income"
            }
          }
        }
      },
      {
        $unwind: "$data"
      },
      {
        $group: {
          _id: null,
          data: {
            $push: "$data"
          },
          netIncome: {
            $sum: "$data.income"
          }
        }
      },
      {
        $unwind: "$data"
      },
      {
        $group: {
          _id: "$data.date",
          date: {
            $first: "$data.date"
          },
          netIncome: {
            $first: "$netIncome"
          },
          dailyIncome: {
            $sum: "$data.income"
          }
        }
      },
      {
        $sort: {
          date: 1
        }
      }
    ])
```

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/ZZBiLyrPUR9)

Sample response

```
[
  {
    "_id": ISODate("2023-06-26T00:00:00Z"),
    "dailyIncome": 600,
    "date": ISODate("2023-06-26T00:00:00Z"),
    "netIncome": 600
  },
  {
    "_id": ISODate("2023-06-27T00:00:00Z"),
    "dailyIncome": 400,
    "date": ISODate("2023-06-27T00:00:00Z"),
    "netIncome": 1000
  },
  {
    "_id": ISODate("2023-06-28T00:00:00Z"),
    "dailyIncome": 200,
    "date": ISODate("2023-06-28T00:00:00Z"),
    "netIncome": 1200
  },
  {
    "_id": ISODate("2023-06-29T00:00:00Z"),
    "dailyIncome": 300,
    "date": ISODate("2023-06-29T00:00:00Z"),
    "netIncome": 1500
  },
  {
    "_id": ISODate("2023-06-30T00:00:00Z"),
    "dailyIncome": 500,
    "date": ISODate("2023-06-30T00:00:00Z"),
    "netIncome": 2000
  }
]
```

Comment: I think you want to explore using `$setWindowFields` (and it'll probably make your overall pipeline much shorter). Eg see [this example](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/setWindowFields/#use-documents-window-to-obtain-cumulative-quantity-for-each-year)

Comment: The date filter is good and takes advantage of what the DB has to offer.   But beyond this, if you just want to extract day over day new total income, don't $group; just add it yourself on the client side.

Comment: Yes I ended up doing ```array = array.map(value => ({
      ...value,
      netIncome: sum += value.dailyIncome
    }))```

Comment: I don't entirely understand the desired output, but if you wanted the MongoDB server to do all the calculations, is this [mongoplayground.net example](https://mongoplayground.net/p/knmmtFQnPZn "Click me!") using `"$setWindowFields"` close to what you're looking for?

Comment: @rickhg12hs yes that's what I want.

Comment: Shall I write it as an answer, or would you like to?  If you write a good answer, I'll upvote it.

Comment: @rickhg12hs yes please